# How to fix ' variable not defined' when trying to call a function to submit to MySQL

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-python

I am new with Tkinter and trying to create a function that will connect to my "Submit" button within my GUI so that it will input data into my MySQL database. The feedback is telling me that `'itemCode_entry' is not defined` within the `def inv_submit():` function. I am trying to get the input from `itemCode_entry` from the `def inv_menu():` function and have it input into the `def inv_submit():` in the MySQL statement.

This is the feedback I get.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Import_Test_Code2.py", line 103, in <lambda>
    submit_btn = Button(btm_frame, text='Submit', bg=color1, command= lambda : inv_submit())
  File "Import_Test_Code2.py", line 207, in inv_submit
    item = itemCode_entry.get()
NameError: name 'itemCode_entry' is not defined
```

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector

#  ======================MySQL Connection================================================================

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "....",
    database = "testdb",
    )

# Create Cursor Instance
my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

# Create Database
#my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE trialProjectdb")

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Database Control')


color1 = 'grey77'
color2 = 'grey88'

item = int()
brandName = StringVar()
#unitsPer = int()
units = int()
cost = float()

#  ======================Frames================================================================

top_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=80, bg=color1)
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)

btm_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, bg=color2)
btm_frame.pack(side=TOP)


#  ======================Inventory=============================================================
inv_btn = Button(top_frame, text='Inventory', width=20,
             command= lambda : inv_menu())
inv_btn.place(x=0, y=0)

#  ======================Functions=============================================================

def inv_menu():

        menu_label = Label(btm_frame, text='Inventory', font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bg=color2)
    menu_label.place(x=200, y=10)

    line = Label(btm_frame, text='______________________________________________________'
                            '________________________________________________', bg=color2)
    line.place(x=0, y=30)

    itemCode_label = Label(btm_frame, text='Item Code:', bg=color2)
    itemCode_label.place(x=22, y=60)

    itemCode_entry = Entry(btm_frame, textvariable=item)
    itemCode_entry.place(x=90, y=60)

    brand_label = Label(btm_frame, text='Brand:', bg=color2)
    brand_label.place(x=45, y=90)

    brand_entry = Entry(btm_frame, textvariable=brandName)
    brand_entry.place(x=90, y=90)

    units_label = Label(btm_frame, text='Units Per:', bg=color2)
    units_label.place(x=28, y=120)

    units_entry = Entry(btm_frame, textvariable=units)
    units_entry.place(x=90, y=120)

    unitCost_label = Label(btm_frame, text='Unit Cost:', bg=color2)
    unitCost_label.place(x=28, y=150)

    unitCost_entry = Entry(btm_frame, textvariable=cost)
    unitCost_entry.place(x=90, y=150)

    submit_btn = Button(btm_frame, text='Submit', bg=color1, command= lambda : inv_submit())
    submit_btn.place(x=90, y=180)


def inv_submit():


    item = itemCode_entry.get()
    brandName = brand_entry.get()
    units = units_entry.get()
    cost = unitCost_entry.get()


    my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST 'trialprojectdb'.'Inventory' (Item_Code INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , Brand VARCHAR(255), Units INTEGER(10), In_Stock INTEGER, Unit_Cost FLOAT(12,2)")

    my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Inventory (itemCode, brand, unitsPer, unitCost) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (item, brandName, units, cost))

    mydb.commit()

    conn.close()



root.mainloop()
```

I expect the "Submit" button `submit_btn`to submit the data to MySQL to update the database once I have filled out the information in the "Inventory" form `inv_menu()`.

Comment: What exactly is itemCode supposed to be? itemCode_entry = Entry(btm_frame, textvariable=itemCode) the "itemCode" is not defined anywhere

Comment: @alex067 Sorry. I tried so many ways to fix it that I put up the wrong code. I just did an edit on the code and output. Thanks.

Comment: [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it a global entry widget:

```
global itemCode_entry
itemCode_entry = Entry(btm_frame, textvariable=item)
itemCode_entry.place(x=90, y=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is with scoping. For example, `item = itemCode_entry.get()` in your inv_submit() function. This is going to cause an issue, because "itemCode_entry.get()" is nowhere to be found within the scope of "inv_submit()" function, nor the global scope of the program.

A possible solution is this:

from

```
dev inv_menu():
...
return itemCode_entry, brand_entry, units_entry, unitCost_entry
```

in your

```
dev inv_submit():
item, brandName, units, cost = inv_menu()
```